# why X86 provides pair of division and multiply instructions?

Tags: c, x86

I noticed that, unsigned int and int shared the same instruction for addition and subtract. But provides idivl / imull for integer division and mutiply,  divl / mull for unsigned int . May I know the underlying reason for this ?

Comment: The result is different, so if there weren't two versions you'd be in trouble. The low half of multiplication is the same for signed and unsigned, so there's only one version of that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The results are different when you multiply or divide, depending on whether your arguments are signed or unsigned.

It's really the magic of two's complement that allows us to use the same operation for signed and unsigned addition and subtraction.  This is not true in other representations -- ones' complement and sign-magnitude both use a different addition and subtraction algorithm than unsigned arithmetic does.

For example, with 32-bit words, `-1` is represented by `0xffffffff`.  Squaring this, you get different results for signed and unsigned versions:

```
Signed: -1 * -1 = 1 = 0x00000000 00000001
Unsigned: 0xffffffff * 0xffffffff = 0xfffffffe 00000001
```

Note that the low word of the result is the same.  On processors that don't give you the high bits, there is only one multiplication instruction necessary.  On PPC, there are three multiplication instructions — one for the low bits, and two for the high bits depending on whether the operands are signed or unsigned.

Comment: On x86, there are also forms of `imul` that give only the low word.

Comment: @harold: And there are also versions of `imul` that operate on GF(2).

Comment: That one's called `pclmulqdq`, so I don't think that counts as a version of `imul`..

Comment: @harold: I was actually thinking of `and`.

Comment: Oh I thought you missed the exponent, oh well. Same idea - not written as `imul` so it doesn't count

Comment: @harold: I said it because it was a non-sequitur.  I'm not really sure why we are counting versions of `imul` in the first place.

Comment: Because your answer is incomplete without that IMO. I mean, PPC is nice and all, but the question was tagged x86 so we might as well mention there's such an instruction on x86 as well, right? It's a piece of this puzzle after all.

Comment: @harold: I must be looking at a different puzzle, sorry.

Comment: Yea I guess so, because in the one I've been looking at, the existence of a low-word only multiply is very relevant.

Comment: So, if we only care the low half, we can use the mul only. For division, can we use div only if we want the low half ?

Comment: @YangBo: Think about this: What is `0xffffffff ÷ 2`?  Is the answer different for signed (`(-1) ÷ 2`) and unsigned (`0xffffffff ÷ 2`)?

Answer (score 0):

Most microprocessors implement multiplication and division with [**shift-and-add algorithm**](http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/~carch/lectures06/55035-060227-prn.pdf) (or a similar algorithm.  This of course requires that the sign of the operands be handled separately.
While implementing multiplication and divisions with add-an-substract would have allowed to not worry about sign and hence allowed to handle signed vs. unsigned integer values interchangeably, it is much less efficient algorithm and that's likely why it wasn't used.

I just read that some modern CPUs use alternatively the [**Booth encoding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth_encoding) method, but that algorithm also implies asserting the sign of the values.

Comment: Might be worth adding some notes to contrast this with add and subtract which can just be done in a straightforward manner no matter whether the inputs are signed or not (just requiring setting the overflow flag to help people out afterwards)

Comment: @Damien: you're quite right; the question indeed mentions addition and subtraction which hints at the idea of `add-and-subtract`. See my edits.  I'm looking for info about the origins of the choices for the implementation of the basic arithmetic operations in CPUs but so far nothing "authoritative".

Answer (score 0):

In x86 sign store in high bit of word (if will talk about integer and unsigned integer)
ADD and SUB command use one algorithm for signed and unsigned in - it get correct result in both.

For MULL and DIV this is not worked. And you should "tell" to CPU what int you want "use" signed or unsigned.
For unsigned use MULL and DIV. It just operate words - it is fast.
For signed use MULL and IDIV. It get word to absolute (positive) value, store sign for result and then make operation. This is slower than MULL and DIV.